# Compute reduced word for element in particular free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let's consider some particular free group, for instance, the example $G = \langle A, B \rangle < \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ in [Wikipedia about ping-pong lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma), and some element $g \in G$.

Problem #1 is to compute the reduced word for this $g$, i.e. the corresponding sequence of factors $A$, $A^{-1}$, $B$, $B^{-1}$ (maybe it's the simple problem, but I can't figure out anything better then iterating over possible sequences).

Problem #2 assumes that we have also some $x$, for example $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and the action $g. x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and we need to find reduced word for $g$ using this information (again, maybe it's easy to reduce problem 2 to problem 1, but I'm confused with this a little).

P.S. The application of this will be the following: given the $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ find the $g \in G$ that might give $y$ by acting on $x$. It's like "rounding" to the nearest group element in embedding space $\mathcal{H}$ if we already embedded $G$ in $\mathcal{H}$, for example, using Švarz–Milnor lemma. So the natural requirement for the procedures in answers on problems 1 and 2 is their computational efficiency, because this "rounding" smust be performed as fast as possible.

Comment: This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.02188  does some of what you want for groups similar to the one in Wiki but the parameters they consider don't include that group.

Comment: This is one of those "well known" things that many people know how to do but that I don't know a good reference for. My  suggestion would be to break this question into two parts. Think of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (slightly easier to work with) as $\langle C\rangle*\langle D\rangle$ where $C$ is of order 2 and $D$ is of order 3. Now algorithmically write $g$ as a product of $C$'s and $D$'s. (This is basically just row reduction.) Next write $A$ and $B$ as products of $C$'s and $D$'s, and it will then be easy to write $g$ as a product of $A$'s and $B$'s.

Answer (score 1):

See the book, Kargapolov-Merzljakov "Fundamentals of group theory", section 14, "Free group". That group is called the "Sanov subgroup" there. The subgroup consists of all $2\times 2$ integral matrices $X$ with $\det(X)=1$, $x_{11}\equiv x_{22}\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $x_{12}\equiv x_{21}\equiv 0\pmod 2$. On page 94 they give an algorithm to represent such a matrix as a product of generators $e_{12}(2), e_{21}(2)$.That representation is unique because the subgroup is free.